# Incorrect escaping in Django SQL query

Tags: python, django

Here's the query I'm trying to run:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(created__lt=functions.TruncDay(Value(timezone.now(), output_field=DateTimeField())))
```

It translates to:

```
SELECT <field-list> FROM "mymodel" WHERE "mymodel"."created" < (DATE_TRUNC('day', %%s AT TIME ZONE %s))
```

before Django performs parameter substitution. Note that the first `%s` has been escaped to `%%s`. This causes the parameter substitution to throw an exception.

Is this intended behaviour or a bug?